# vue-scrollto scrollTo('#id') scrolls more than expected on windows 11 and some mac devices

Tags: javascript, vue.js, scroll

I'm using vue-scrollto in my component to scroll to an element with specific 'id'.
For windows 10 it scrolls to proper location of the element in the page, but for Chrome on Windows 11 and for some mac devices (Safari) it scrolls some additional pixels than expected.

I've used it as below:

```
import VueScrollTo from 'vue-scrollto';
...
this.$scrollTo('#ratings')
```